# Auto open textmate project on startup

Tags: macos, textmate

How do I get textmate to remember what project i had open last and reopen it automatically?

Right now I have to select it from the menu.

Comment: not working for me also... Tried both: defaults write com.macromates.textmate NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool NO defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDisableSessionRestore 0 Nothing seemed to get previous projects and files to open. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default TextMate should open the last open project or document - but it can be switched on/off - maybe it is off by you ??

Here is how to switch the feature on/off: http://manual.macromates.com/en/expert_preferences#oakdisablesessionrestore

> **22.7 OakDisableSessionRestore**
>
> When you launch TextMate it will open the project / document which was open when you last exited. You can however disable this feature by running:
>
> `defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDisableSessionRestore 1`

This means that you should run the above line in a Terminal - with a 0 instead of 1

Comment: Strange, totally not working for me, though this appears to be the "right" answer.

Answer (score 0):

This command allowed me to re-open a project (I'm running Mountain Lion):

```
    defaults write com.macromates.textmate NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool NO
```

TextMate needs to be **closed** when you issue Terminal commands, otherwise they will not work.

See [this](http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/Lion) page for more information.

Make sure you created a TextMate project using TextMate. In other words, do not drag a folder into TextMate and assume that all the open-file states to be reloaded.  You must have a `.tmproj` file into which you drag your files into.